# How to process a CPU-bound task in async code

Tags: python-asyncio

I am doing some heavy processing that needs async methods.  One of my methods returns a list of dictionaries that needs to go through heavy processing prior to adding  it to another awaitable object.  ie.

````
def cpu_bound_task_here(record):
    ```some complicated preprocessing of record```
    return record
````

After the answer given below by the kind person, my code is now just stuck.

```
async def fun():
print("Socket open")
record_count = 0
symbol = obj.symbol.replace("-", "").replace("/", "")
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
await obj.send()

while True:
    try:
        records = await obj.receive()
        if not records:
            continue

        record_count += len(records)
```

So what the above function does, is its streaming values asynchronously and does some heavy processing prior to pushing to redis indefinitely.  I made the necessary changes and now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As that output tells you, `run_in_executor` returns a `Future`. You need to await it to get its result.

```
record = await loop.run_in_executor(
    None, something_cpu_bound_task_here, record
)
```

Note that any arguments to `something_cpu_bound_task_here` need to be passed to `run_in_executor`.

Additionally, as you've mentioned that this is a CPU-bound task, you'll want to make sure you're using a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. Unless you've called `loop.set_default_executor` somewhere, the default is an instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for record in records:
        record = await loop.run_in_executor(
            executor, something_cpu_bound_task_here, record
        )
```

Finally, your while loop is effectively running synchronously. You need to wait for the future and then for `obj.add` before moving on to process the next item in `records`. You might want to restructure your code a bit and use something like `gather` to allow for some concurrency.

```
async def process_record(record, obj, loop, executor):
    record = await loop.run_in_executor(
        executor, something_cpu_bound_task_here, record
    )
    await obj.add(record)

async def fun():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    records = await receive()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        await asyncio.gather(
            *[process_record(record, obj, loop, executor) for record in records]
        )
```

I'm not sure how to handle `obj` since that isn't defined in your example, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: hey, my obj is actually a redis stream.  Its from the aioredis library that im trying to add records to this stream.  But prior to adding records, i am doing some complicated preprocessing of these records.

Comment: i changed the question to better reflect what im actually trying to do

Comment: hey, i tried your method but now its causing my code to break.  pasted my code here, curious if you could help?

Comment: my code is now stuck for some reason

Comment: Where is it stuck? Knowing that would make it a lot easier to tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the library [Pypeln](https://cgarciae.github.io/pypeln/), it is perfect for streaming tasks between process, thread, and asyncio pools:

```py
import pypeln as pl
data = get_iterable()
data = pl.task.map(f1, data, workers=100) # asyncio
data = pl.thread.flat_map(f2, data, workers=10)
data = filter(f3, data)
data = pl.process.map(f4, data, workers=5, maxsize=200)
```